# distribution of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

> A fair coin with $0$ on one side and $1$ on the other side is tossed. If the result is $0$, a fair dice is rolled, otherwise, the coin is tossed again. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the numbers that show up on the first and second experiment, respectively. What is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$?

(In other words: The first experiment is to roll a coin (X may be 0 or 1). If the result is 0, then the second experiment is to roll a fair die. else, the result was 1 so the second experiment is to roll the same coin again. That's why Y can be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.)

My solution which is incorrect:

- $X$ can have the following values: 0,1.
- $Y$ can have the following values: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.
- The possible events are: $(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(1,0),(1,1)$.

(We can conclude that $P(Y=0)=\frac{1}{8}$)

$$P(X=x \cap Y=y) = \sum_{x=0}^{1} P(X=x \cap Y=y| X=x)*P(X=x)$$
$$= \sum_{x=0}^{1} \frac{P(X=x \cap Y=y \cap X=x)}{P(X=x)}*P(X=x)$$
$$= \sum_{x=0}^{1} P(X=x \cap Y=y \cap X=x) = \sum_{x=0}^{1} P(Y=y | X=x)*P(X=x) $$ 
Which is:
$$ = P(Y=y) $$

$$ = P(Y=y | X=0)*P(X=0) + P(Y=y | X=1)*P(X=1) $$

if $y=0$ then it equals to $0 + \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$ (Which is not true because earlier I menually calculated $P(Y=0)$ which is equal to $\frac{1}{8}$).

if $y=1$ then it equals to $\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{3}$.

if $2<=y<=6$ then it equals to $\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{2} + 0=\frac{1}{12}$.

#### Where is my mistake?

Comment: The $Y$ distribution cannot take a value of $0$.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  What are the two experiments here?  What if the die isn't rolled at all?

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that what you mean to say is "$X$ is the result of the first coin toss.  $Y$ is either the result of the dice roll or the result of the second coin toss, depending on the value of $X$."

Comment: @lulu the first experiment is to roll a coin ($X$ may be 0 or 1). If the result is $0$, then the second experiment is to roll a fair die. else, the result was $1$ so the second experiment is to roll the same coin again. That's why $Y$ can be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: @lulu Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Ok, I suggest editing your post for clarity.

Comment: As a quick computation, for $P(Y=0)$, we see that we just need the coin to come up $1$ first then $0$.  Hence $P(Y=0)= \frac 14$.  You seem to feel the outcomes are all equiprobable but that is not the case.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! the sum of the distribution of $Y$ needs to be equal to $1$ but it's not. Why?

Comment: It is.  $P(Y=0)=\frac 14$.  $P(Y=1)=\frac 12\times \frac 16+\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 13$, and for $6≥i≥2$ we have $P(Y=i)=\frac 12\times \frac 16=\frac 1{12}$.  Then we note that $\frac 14+\frac 13+\frac 5{12}=1$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! but I still think that something is broken because I proved that  $P(X=x \cap Y=y)=P(Y=y)$ and this prof may work for every $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I don't believe you proved that.  $P(X=1\cap Y=2)=0\neq P(Y=2)$, for instance.